# How to split the indexes of a string?

Tags: python, string

When I try to split this string:

```
str1 = ("S8 10 -945 1689 -950 230 -25 1 1e-13")
print(str1[0,1].split(' '))
```

I get this error 
print(str1[0,1].split(' '))
TypeError: string indices must be integers

How would I split this the first two indexes of this string in python?

Comment: What are you trying to do by `str1[0,1]` ? (which is illegal syntax)

Comment: are you asking how to get the first two terms in the string?

Comment: What do you want the result to be? What do you mean by "indexes"?

Answer (score 0):

[`.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) the string first, and then [slice the list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/703229) to retrieve the first two values.

```
str = "S8 10 -945 1689 -950 230 -25 1 1e-13"
print str.split(' ')[:2]  # ['S8', '10']
```

Comment: And to avoid unnecessary work, pass the `maxsplit` argument to split so it doesn't split beyond the point you care about: `print str1.split(' ', 2)[:2]` does the same thing, while avoiding excess work.

Comment: How would I split the S8 of the first index?

Comment: @Sam: Nope, second argument is 2, not 3. It's the maximum number of splits, not the number of components produced (which is `maxsplits + 1`, assuming there are at least `maxsplits` split points). If you only want two components, you only need two splits, one for each component. Python differs from some other languages here.

Comment: How do you ***want*** to split the `S8` of the first index?